# Find out which of my Google Apps accounts controls a YouTube account

Tags: youtube, google-workspace

We have a YouTube account that's a few years old and we're trying to get back to using it. The problem is we don't know which of our Google Apps users created the account, so we can't even login to transfer it to another account.

None of the employees that worked directly with the YouTube account still work here and I've checked most of the accounts I can think of. Is there any way as a Google Apps administrator to see or control YouTube accounts created under our domain?

Comment: I have since found the Google account that owned the Youtube channel and was able to acquire access. Unfortunately I just got lucky with guessing the account connected and then reset the password so I have still been unable to find a good way to be able to determine who owns an account without already knowing up front.